# Slide Element Off Screen -- Wait --- Slide Back in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to slide an image (of a boomerang) off screen and then 5 seconds later slide it back into place. I want the image to right next to some text to begin with and end.

Ideally I'd like the animation to be smooth. I can find many examples doing things like this, but none that seem to do this very simple thing. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
 {
      var my_div = $("#target");
      var div_top = my_div.offset().top;

      $(document).scroll(function()
        {
          if (div_top <= $(document).scrollTop()+($(window).height() /2))
            {
             // EVENT TO SEND IMAGE OFF SCREEN TO THE RIGHT
             // EVENT TO WAIT 5 SECONDS
             // EVENT TO SEND THE IMAGE BACK
            }
        });
 });
```

```html
<div id="target;">
  <p style="font-size:32px; display: inline;">TEXT</p>
  <img id="foo" style="height:35px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Ic_account_box_48px.svgg">
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question with javascript and provide code that's an incomplete javascript solution, but you also mention you want it to be smooth.

Perhaps declaring a CSS animation using transforms would be better?
Check out https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ for some examples of what a CSS animation can do. And they can be quite complex, as you can define as many steps as needed.

Now if in some of your animation steps you need to perform calculations, you're stuck with JS, but you can still use a library that uses CSS transitions under the hood get get a smooth frame-rate.

I've used `move.js` for such a task in the past, and worked pretty well.
https://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/